# Single context with many threads with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework

I have the following:

```
           await Task.WhenAll(
                 Task.Run(() => HandleJob("one"),
                 Task.Run(() => HandleJob("two"),
                 Task.Run(() => HandleJob("three"));
```

Where HandleJob is this:

```
       private async Task HandleJob(string param) {
              using (var db = new DbContext()) {
                     _numberService = new NumberService(db);
                     _numberService.DoThis(param);
              }
       }
```

And NumberService is this:

```
    public class NumberService {

           private readonly DbContext db;

           private CommService _commService;

           public NumberService(DbContext db) {
              this.db = db;
              _commService = new CommService(db);
           }


           public void DoThis(string param){
              _commService.DoThat(param);   
           }

     }
```

And CommService is this:

```
     public class CommService {

           private readonly DbContext db;

           public CommService(DbContext db) {
              this.db = db;
           }

           public void DoThat(string param){
              db.Things.Add(param);
              db.SaveChanges();
           }

     }
```

I'm running into a problem where I see the following when I try to run this:

> An exception of type System.InvalidOperationException 
>   occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code The context
>   cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be
>   thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if
>   the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads
>   concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related
>   classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

What am I doing wrong?  I thought that by using a new `dbContext` for each thread, I would be ok.

Comment: Seems fine to me. I've seen that error before; it can basically mean various things. Post the whole callstack where this happens. Try this before the await keyword: `using (var dbCOntext = new DbContext())
    dbCOntext.Database.Initialize(force: false);
`

Comment: It might not be a threading issue, you might be executing the code on that new context when it doesn't exist yet or is still being created.

Comment: db.Things.Add(param); is wrong because param is a string and not an instance if Thing. It then proceed to throw an exception, which was not handle

Comment: @TienDinh that was just a syntactical error - I'm simplifying the code here.

Comment: Looking back at your code, I can see so many syntactical errors. I doubt that your problem codes are included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot.  It was because I defined `_numberService` outside of the async method so every async usage over-wrote the context for the others.  Doh.